# Excluding a folder from applying them in Web.Config

Tags: web-config, themes

I use Asp.net 4, in my Web.Config (in the root for my site) I have this code

```
<pages enableViewState="true" theme="Cms-FE-01" validateRequest="true">
        </pages>
```

I need exclude applying of theme="Cms-FE-01" for a subfolder.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem adding in the sub folder a new web.config with this settings

```
<pages enableViewState="true" theme="" validateRequest="true">
        </pages>
```

if you guys know another way please post. thanks!